# Meaning of "Don't look down upon your own kind"

Tags: indian-english

What is the meaning of "Don't look down upon your own kind"?

This sentence has been used when one person is upset or frustrated about something.

Can anyone explain a little bit about this.

Comment: Hi saravanan, have you visited our site for [ell.se]?

Comment: nope. i will look at your website. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *look down upon someone* (or *look down on someone*) is to view them as inferior. (The reverse is to *look up to someone*, which is to admire them.) *One's own kind* is other people who are like oneself.

Assuming you are referring to the passage from Chetan Bhagat's *Revolution 2020*, Gopal has just used the phrase "other losers" in reference to other (hypothetical) people in the same position as him; by saying "Don't look down upon your own kind", Vineet is reminding him that, since he's in the same position, he is no better than they.